# Adding border to ag-grid column groupings/ pivot

Tags: ag-grid

Is it possible to add a border to the pivot groupings (or possibly just column groupings) on ag-grid? My groups are quite wide and I'm using material theme which makes it hard to read the grid clearly.

There doesn't seem to be any api exposed or css class to use?

e.g. *sum (gold)* or whatever column is on the left of the group would have border-left css to demark from the previous group.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-pivoting/#example-simple-pivot

Answer (score 0):

Try to add cellClass and headerClass.

Add CSS to this class and also to ag-header-group-cell-with-group.

Plunkr:
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/ZQ1rv0cwau99oarH

Comment: Thanks but breaks as soon as you move columns, hardcoding not really an option